# FastLED: "Invalid pin specified"

Tags: rgb-led, attiny85, compilation-errors

I have an **Adafruit Trinket (5v, 16mhz, based off of the AtTiny85 chip)**, and am wishing to use it with a strip with 24 **3 pin, individually addressable LEDs (WS2812B)**. When I try to compile my code, I get this error:  `static_assert(validpin(), "Invalid pin specified");` I've tried using different pins, but of them are seeming to work. What can I do to fix this issue? Here's my current code:

```
#include <FastLED.h>
#define LEDCOUNT 24
#define DATAPIN 0

CRGB leds[LEDCOUNT];

void setup() {
  FastLED.addLeds<WS2812B, LEDCOUNT>(leds, LEDCOUNT);
}

void loop() {
  leds[0] = CRGB::Red;
  FastLED.show();
  delay(30);
}
```

Comment: Where is pin 24 on a ATtiny85?

Comment: No idea. I am using this:https://www.adafruit.com/product/1501

Answer (score 1):

I think what @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams is getting at is:

```
void setup() {
  FastLED.addLeds<WS2812B, LEDCOUNT>(leds, LEDCOUNT);
}
```

Has `LEDCOUNT` showing up for both the number of LEDs and the data pin identifier.

Try:

```
void setup() {
  FastLED.addLeds<WS2812B, DATAPIN, GRB>(leds, LEDCOUNT);
}
```

This puts `DATAPIN` in the right place, and also adds the color order typical for WS2812B, `GRB`

Comment: Tried this. Still got an error.

Comment: "No hardware SPI pins defined.  All SPI access will default to bitbanged output"

Comment: Wait.. it worked though.

Comment: That's just a warning, not an error. ATTiny doesn't have hardware SPI that FastLED can use.